# Google Books like image slider

Tags: jquery, image, jquery-plugins, javascript

I have a folder containing images. I want to have an image slider, like the one we can see in [Google Books](http://books.google.com) for browsing books. It has a number of images in a bar, and slides according to the arrow buttons located on both sides. Does anybody have a (similar) solution?

Here is a screen capture:

[image: image slider]

Comment: How did you get on with jCarousel?

Comment: @AlexThomas it works. Do u have any other solution(s)??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[jCarousel](http://sorgalla.com/jcarousel/) is your friend.